# Merge two lists and output

Tags: terraform

I'd like to feed the external and internal IP address of my Azure VMs into a Python script, in the format `script.py external1,internal1 external2,internal2 external3,internal3` e.g. `script.py 54.120.31.31,192.168.0.1 54.32.13.14,192.168.0.2 54.33.16.19,192.168.0.3`.

I can get the required outputs using this command, just not in the right format:

```
output "inventory" {
  value = "${
    formatlist(
      "%s,%s",
      azurerm_public_ip.main.*.ip_address,
      azurerm_network_interface.main.*.private_ip_address
    )
  }"
}
```

Is it possible to amalgamate these lists into my desired output format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were close:

```
output "inventory" {
  value = "${
    join(
      " ",
      formatlist(
        "%s,%s",
        azurerm_public_ip.main.*.ip_address,
        azurerm_network_interface.main.*.private_ip_address
      )
    )
  }"
}
```

Example:

```
output "inventory" {
  value = "${
    join(
      " ",
      formatlist(
        "%s,%s",
        list("1", "2", "3"),
        list("a", "b", "c")
      )
    )
  }"
}
```

```
> terraform apply

Apply complete! Resources: 0 added, 0 changed, 0 destroyed.

Outputs:

inventory = 1,a 2,b 3,c
```

Comment: Hi @beatcracker, thank you for this. I read your answer on my phone last night and awarded you the mighty Green Tick, but upon re-reading, I've made a mistake - this isn't quite right.

I need the `inventory` output to appear with spaces, e.g. `1,a 2,b 3,c` - one entry from the first list, then a comma, then the first entry from the second list - then a space, then repeat.

Comment: @dunc No problem, you just need to join with space then. I've updated my answer.

Comment: Duhh, I probably should've been able to do that myself if I'd just had a quick look at the syntax... :) Sorry dude, re-applying the Green Tick now. Thanks!